# How to display innerHTML values one by one javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to display the values of my inner HTML, from 10 to 1, but am able to show only the value 1.

the values should display, one by one..
For example if 10 get displays, it should hide and then 9 should display,
it just like a timer.

How to fix this, this is what I have tried.

HTML:

```
<div id='test'></div>
```

JS:

```
var a = 10;
var b=1;
var tar = document.getElementById('test');

for(var a=10;a>=b;a--){
    tar.innerHTML = a;    
    if(a==b){
        tar.innerHTML = a;
        //tar.style.display='none';
        window.location.href = "http://www.google.co.in";
    }
}
```

[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0sbu5f8c/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that JavaScript can execute incredibly fast, so it is counting from 10 to 1 faster than you can see. You need to slow it down a little with a timer...

In this example, there is a one second delay between each number.

```
var a = 10;
var b = 1;
var tar = document.getElementById('test');
var timer;

function countDown() {
    tar.innerHTML = a;    
    if(a === b) {
        tar.innerHTML = a;
        //tar.style.display = 'none';
        window.location.href = "http://www.google.co.in";
    } else {
        a--;
        timer = window.setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
    }
}

countDown();
```

Comment: @SteveFenton: How the user may know that the timer is started, its not showing on the page..

Comment: The timer shows in the `<div id='test'></div>` tag you already have.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    var myVar = setInterval(function(){myTimer()}, 1000);
    var i=10;
function myTimer() {
    i--;
    if(i==1)
        clearInterval(myVar);
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = i;

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you are finished in this example, you should use `window.clearInterval(myVar)` to stop the timer executing. You can also use the shorter `setInterval(myTimer, 1000)`.

Comment: You can use `clearInterval(myVar);` instead of `return false;` in `if` condition so that timer will stop.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
var counter = 10; // number of iterations
var tar = document.getElementById('test');    
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    if (counter === 0) clearInterval(interval); // skip if reached end
    tar.innerHTML = counter; // update html
    counter--; // update counter value
}, 1000) // 1000 = 1 second
```

### [See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0sbu5f8c/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/0sbu5f8c/13/

```
var a = 10;
var b = 1;
var tar = document.getElementById('test');
var timer = setInterval(function () {
    tar.innerHTML = a;
    if(a === b) {
        window.clearInterval(timer);
        //window.location.href = "http://www.google.co.in";
    }
    a -= 1;
}, 500);
```